# Inline sorting of complex type sequence

Tags: sorting, nim-lang

I have the following problem:

I have a table mapping point IDs (`uint16`) to `Points` (`tuple[x: float64, y: float64]`). Given three point IDs, I want to create a `Triangle` which is a triple of point IDs sorted by their x-values (and secondarily sorted by y-values).

I create a `Triangle` by passing to a constructor the three point IDs and the table. It should then pick the corresponding `Point`s from the table, sort them accordingly, and return the triangle.

However, I cannot manage to get the inline sorting to work. The error is thrown on the line where I call `vec.sort`. I pasted it below the code.

```
import tables
import system

type
  Point* = tuple[x: float64, y: float64]
  PointData* = tuple[id: uint16, point: Point]
  Triangle* = tuple[left: uint16, middle: uint16, right: uint16]

proc createTriangle*(p1: uint16, p2: uint16, p3: uint16, pointToPosition: Table[uint16, Point]): Triangle =
  if p1 in pointToPosition and p2 in pointToPosition and p3 in pointToPosition:
    let t1: PointData = (p1, pointToPosition[p1])
    let t2: PointData = (p2, pointToPosition[p2])
    let t3: PointData = (p3, pointToPosition[p3])
    var vec = @[t1, t2, t3]
    vec.sort do (a, b: PointData) -> int:
      result = system.cmp(a.point.x, b.point.x)
      if result == 0:
        result = system.cmp(a.point.y, b.point.y)
    result = (vec[0].id, vec[1].id, vec[2].id)
  else:
    raise newException(SystemError, "tried to create Triangle with unknown point IDs")
```

The Error:

```
types.nim(31, 8) Error: type mismatch: got (seq[PointData], void)
but expected one of: 
proc sort[A](t: CountTableRef[A])
proc sort[A, B](t: var OrderedTable[A, B]; cmp: proc (x, y: (A, B)): int)
proc sort[A, B](t: OrderedTableRef[A, B]; cmp: proc (x, y: (A, B)): int)
proc sort[A](t: var CountTable[A])
```

For some reason there is a type mismatch with my inline sorting proc. It says it got `void` instead of it. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right, except you forgot to import module `algorithm`, where sort for `seq`s is defined. Also import `system` is not needed as it is always imported implicitly.